# How can I identify which diseases are Supernatural (and which diseases are other types)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, disease

How do I identify which diseases are "supernatural" and which diseases are other types?

I hoping for a property in the [disease](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/diseases/diseases-paizo-inc/)'s stat block, but cannot find anything that makes the determination of the type of disease!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry: those pages don’t mention it. I’m not sure if it’s because none of them are supernatural, or because the information just isn’t included, but running this:

```
(await Promise.all(
  [...new Set(
    [...document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/diseases/diseases-paizo-inc/"]')]
      .map(a => a.href)
  )].map(
    async (href) => [
      href,
      (await (await fetch(href)).text())
    ]
  )
))
  .filter(([href, body]) => /supernatural|\(Su\)/i.test(body))
  .map(([href, body]) => href)
```

in the Console on the page you link returns nothing. This code gets each of the Paizo disease pages and then filters the list by which ones have “supernatural” or “(Su)” in them—none do.

Instead, the place to find if a disease is supernatural or not is going to be in monster stat blocks, where it will inherit the type of the special ability that inflicts the disease. For instance, the [carrion golem](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-carrion/) has “Plague Carrior (Ex),” indicating that its filth fever is extraordinary (read: not supernatural), while the [mummy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/mummy/) has “Mummy Rot (Su),” indicating that its mummy rot is supernatural. Notably, filth fever appears in your list, but mummy rot does not—so that list might be only the natural, non-supernatural diseases, perhaps.

Finally, it’s possible for a disease to be extraordinary for one monster and supernatural for another. I don’t know any examples of that—I kind of suspect there aren’t any—but since diseases are each individual qualities of individual monsters, they could have different designations despite otherwise having the same name and effect.

Comment: So because the disease itself could be any 'classification' or 'type' it isn't mentioned, and it is the source of the disease which determines whether a disease is supernatural or extraordinary or just plain normal. Weird way to do it, I suppose it supports 'strains' though.

Comment: I find it unhelpful when they group disease into a special attack though, Barbazu for example. I can see how the 'wire beard' attack causing so much damage is an Extraordinary attack, but is Devil Chills (a disease) which rides on the beard attack also just Extraordinary? Surely a disease borne of an infernal creature is by definition Supernatural?!

Comment: @niekell Ultimately, it is this way because there *wasn’t any* centralized, standardized list of diseases. Every disease was defined solely by the monster it appeared on, and if it happened to have the same name and effect as another monster’s, as far as the rules were concerned that was just coincidence. Attempts to come up with any central repository came after the CRB, I believe, and in any event _certainly_ didn’t appear in D&D 3.5e. But anyway, I would treat Ex as the default when it truly isn’t specified (dunno what “just plain normal” would mean to you).

Comment: @niekell And yes, that includes the devil chills inflicted by the barbazu’s beard—why couldn’t a devil have or impart a non-magical disease? If a devil hits you with a nonmagical sword, there’s nothing magical about the wound (unless something, like the barbazu’s infernal wound attack, says it is). Nothing says devil chills are magical or supernatural. It’s inflicted by an extraordinary attack. Ergo, it is itself extraordinary.